# How to determine if a point lies within an sf geometry that spans the dateline?

Tags: r, mapping, tidyverse, gis, r-sf

Using the R package `sf`, I'm trying to determine whether some points occur within the bounds of a shapefile (in this case, Hawai‘i's, EEZ). The shapefile in question can be found [here](https://maritimeboundaries.noaa.gov/downloads/USMaritimeLimitsAndBoundariesSHP.zip). Unfortunately, the boundaries of the area in question span +/-180 longitude, which I think is what's messing me up. (I read on the sf website some business about spherical geometry in the new version, but I haven't been able to get that version to install. I think the polygons I'm dealing with are sufficiently "flat" to avoid any of those issues anyway). Part of the issue seems to be that my shapefile contains multiple geometries broken up by the dateline but I'm not sure how to combine them.

How do you tell, using sf, whether some points are inside of the bounds of some object in a shapefile (that happens to span the dateline)?

I have tried various combinations of `st_shift_longitude` to no avail. I have also tried transforming to what I think is a planar projection (2163), and that didn't work.

Here's how I'm currently trying to do this:

```
library(sf)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# this is the shapefile from the link above
eez_unshifted <- read_sf("USMaritimeLimitsAndBoundariesSHP/USMaritimeLimitsNBoundaries.shp") %>%
  filter(OBJECTID == 1206) %>%
  st_transform(4326) 

eez_shifted <- read_sf("USMaritimeLimitsAndBoundariesSHP/USMaritimeLimitsNBoundaries.shp") %>%
  filter(OBJECTID == 1206) %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_shift_longitude()

# four points, in and out of the geometry, on either side of the dateline
pnts <- tibble(x=c(-171.952474,176.251978,179.006220,-167.922929),y=c(25.561970,17.442716,28.463375,15.991429)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords=c('x','y'),crs=st_crs(eez_unshifted))  


# these all return false for every point
st_within(pnts,eez_unshifted)
st_within(st_shift_longitude(pnts),eez_unshifted)
st_within(pnts,eez_shifted)
st_within(st_shift_longitude(pnts),eez_shifted)

# these also all return false for every point
st_intersects(pnts,eez_unshifted)
st_intersects(st_shift_longitude(pnts),eez_unshifted)
st_intersects(pnts,eez_shifted)
st_intersects(st_shift_longitude(pnts),eez_shifted)
  
# plot the data just to show that it looks right
wrld2 <- st_as_sf(maps::map('world2', plot=F, fill=T))
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=wrld2, fill='gray20',color="lightgrey",size=0.07) +
  geom_sf(data=eez_shifted) + 
  geom_sf(data=st_shift_longitude(pnts)) + 
  coord_sf(xlim=c(100,290), ylim=c(-60,60)) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude")
```

Comment: It looks like if I construct a convex hull around my EEZ geometry, st_within works as I hoped, indicating that the shapefile is not a "complete" geometry. Is there some way to "close" the shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to make sure the geometry you're checking against is a polygon:

```r
> eez_poly <- st_polygonize(eez_shifted)
> st_within(pnts,eez_poly)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_within assumes that they are planar
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 4, where the predicate was `within'
 1: 1
 2: (empty)
 3: 1
 4: (empty)
```